# Log4j2: Log ERROR level into a specific file

Tags: log4j2

In my log4j2 configuration, I have an *AsyncRoot* set to INFO because I want to log this level and upper in a file.

But I would like also to log the *ERROR* level into a specific file AND in the appender configured in the *AsyncRoot*

Here is my configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${LOG_PATH}/${APP_NAME}.log" filePattern="${LOG_PATH}/${APP_NAME}-${FILE_PATTERN_TRAILER}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="errorFile" fileName="${LOG_PATH}/${APP_NAME}-errors.log" filePattern="${LOG_PATH}/${APP_NAME}-errors-${FILE_PATTERN_TRAILER}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </AsyncRoot>

        <AsyncLogger level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="errorFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is the logging behaviour I'd like to achieve (no matter the package) :

- All the logs with INFO log level are logged into the appender *file*
- All the logs with ERROR log level are logged into the appender *file* and *errorFile*
- All the logs with a lower log level (DEBUG, TRACE) aren't logged at all

Thank you

Comment: You mean logs with HIGHER log levels not to be logged at all? Since DEBUG level (500) has higher (integer) value than INFO (400) does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by setting the `root` logger's level to `info` since you don't want any `trace` or `debug` events to reach your appenders. Set the `level` on the error file appender to `error` so that only events of that level or more specific are written to the file.

Here's a simple example that you can adapt to your needs:

Java class to generate some log events

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.debug("This is some debug!");
        log.info("Here's some info!");
        log.error("Some error happened!");
    }
}
```

log4j2 XML config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="ErrorFile" fileName="logs/errors.log" immediateFlush="false"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>

        <File name="InfoFile" fileName="logs/Info.log" immediateFlush="false"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="InfoFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ErrorFile" level="error" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This generates 2 files: errors.log and Info.log

The error log contains only the error:

```
2019-12-04 10:05:34.672 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - Some error happened!
```

The info log contains the info and error events:

```
2019-12-04 10:05:34.670 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - Here's some info!
2019-12-04 10:05:34.672 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - Some error happened!
```

Answer (score 1):

To do similar thing in the properties config file you can set config file as below

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
 
filters = threshold
 
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug
 
appenders = rolling, rollingErrorFile
 
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = logs.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs.log.%i
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p %30.30c{2} : %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=20 MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

appender.rollingErrorFile.type = RollingFile
appender.rollingErrorFile.name = RollingErrorFile
appender.rollingErrorFile.fileName = logsErrors.log
appender.rollingErrorFile.filePattern = logsErrors.log.%i
appender.rollingErrorFile.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rollingErrorFile.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p %30.30c{2} : %m%n
appender.rollingErrorFile.policies.type = Policies
appender.rollingErrorFile.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rollingErrorFile.policies.size.size=20 MB
appender.rollingErrorFile.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rollingErrorFile.strategy.max = 20
 
loggers = rolling
 
#Make sure to change the package structure as per your application
logger.rolling.name = example
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rollingErrorFile.ref = RollingErrorFile
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rollingErrorFile.level = error
```